# Express.JS net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED for static assets

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

So I'm making a simple Express.JS web app.
I have some assets in /public (for example, `public/images/main-back.png` ).
In index.scss I do:

```
background-image: url('../../../images/main-back.png');
```

And in Chrome console I get an error:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/images/main-back.png net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

When I refresh the page several times, this request may pass one time and the image will show on the page.

The configuration is more or less default, I have the default bin/www file. It listens on port 3000:

```
var server = http.createServer(app);

/**
 * Listen on provided port, on all network interfaces.
 */

server.listen(port);
```

The app has pre-configured assets serving by default. in app.js I have:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

The question is - why is it not working?

UPD: In the default project which was created by Express generator, there is

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

in app.js. I added app.use(sassMiddleware) before this app.use, and this leaded to the bug I'm talking about. But when I place the app.use(sassMiddleware) after the

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

Then the css files don't update on scss file change. What should I do?

Comment: What do you want to render?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I found a solution. I think this may be helpful for others.
In the default project which was created by Express generator, the

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

in app.js was not the first "app.use(...)" in the file.
Place it on top of all the other "app.use(...)" and everything will be fine.
Have a good day!

Comment: THANK YOU!!, cant believe that was my issue